How to block any api based on header with chrome extension manifest_version 3
I want to block an API based on headers. I write rules for that. But it blocked all the same APIs, and even the headers did not match. How can I do this in manifest_version 3? I add my codes in the below. please suggest a solution or alternative way to do this.
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequest", "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.bac.com/*"
  ],
"declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}

rules.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "block"
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "abcde.com/api/graphql/",
      "resourceTypes": ["xmlhttprequest"],
      "requestHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "x-name",
          "operation": "equals",
          "value": "isNotReady"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]


As you can see in the documentation, requestHeaders is not available as a condition. It's not yet implemented and I don't see any plans to do so in the near future. The workaround is to override fetch and/or XMLHttpRequest in the MAIN world, see these examples.
